# Hide links with css

Tags: html, css

I want to hide one or more links in this menu bar using CSS.
I've tried a few hundred combinations but haven't been able to make it work.
For example, trying to hide MYPAGE link

```
<div id="siteNav">
<ul>
<div id="pnlProjectAdmin">  
<li><div id="distribute"></div></li>
<li><div id="generate"><div id="generatePanel">
</div></div></li>
<li><div></div></li>
</div>
<div id="pnlTopLinks">
<li class="projectShortcuts"></li>
<li class="home"><a id="ctl00_lnkHome" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$lnkHome&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><span><span id="lblHome">Hem</span></span></a></li>
<li class="mypage"><a id="ctl00_lnkMyPage" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$lnkMyPage&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><span><span id="lblMyPage">Min sida</span></span></a></li>
<li class="manual"></li>
<li class="logout"><a id="ctl00_lnkLogout" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$lnkLogout&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><span><span id="lblLogout">Logga ut</span></span></a></li>                  
</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which links and what have you tried. Are you trying to hide the links or the list items?

Comment: `<a style="display:none">`

Comment: "*I want to hide one or more links*" - which is it? Which specific link(s) did you want to hide? "*...using CSS*" - where's your attempt? What, specifically, have you tried? How did it fail? What did it do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pnlTopLinks .mypage { display: none; }
```

Comment: this worked great. Thought i tried every combination. But was it the space betweekn pnlTopLinks and .mypage that did the trick?
Thanks anyways!

Comment: @nils just be aware the you're hiding the list-item and not the link as you asked.

Comment: I was aware of this, but I thought he wanted to get rid of the item holding the link. Others should keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hide the link contained into `.mypage` element then define

```
.mypage a { display: none }
```

or trying to define a rule whose specificity is as low as possible you may also write

```
[id="ctl00_lnkMyPage"] { display: none }
```

which is equivalent to

```
#ctl00_lnkMyPage { display: none }
```

---

but if you need to hide the entire list-item instead then just define

```
.mypage { display: none }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:none in your css....

```
.mypage
{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: oops, i will edit my answer